# Where Subquery take too long, need to optmize

Tags: mysql, performance

```
SELECT PROJECTKEY, CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME) as USRCREATED,
                              CONCAT('/userImages/',md.USERKEY,'/',md.IMAGE) as USRCREATED_PROFILE_IMG,mm.DTCREATED
                              FROM kbedumoment mm
                              left join users md on mm.USRCREATED=md.USERKEY

where mm.id in
(

SELECT mm.id from kbedumoment mm
left join kbedumomentpostto pt on pt.MOMENT_ID=mm.id
where mm.deleted_at is NULL
   && pt.childkey=1005

union all

SELECT id from kbedumoment mm
where POST_TO='school' && mm.deleted_at is NULL && mm.PROJECTKEY =2

)                              


order by mm.id desc
```

Query above take 6.875 sec, which is taking too long.

[image]

I tried to execute the subquery alone.

```
SELECT mm.id from kbedumoment mm
left join kbedumomentpostto pt on pt.MOMENT_ID=mm.id
where mm.deleted_at is NULL
   && pt.childkey=1005

union

SELECT id from kbedumoment mm
where POST_TO='school' && mm.deleted_at is NULL && mm.PROJECTKEY =2
```

Result :

```
+-------+
| id    |
+-------+
|  253  |
|  1264 |
|  1    |
|  238  |
+-------+
```

Duration: 0.109 sec. So the subquery is fine.

Then I perform the following for testing, replace the subquery with the ids I've already know.

```
SELECT PROJECTKEY, CONCAT(FIRSTNAME,' ',LASTNAME) as USRCREATED,
                              CONCAT('/userImages/',md.USERKEY,'/',md.IMAGE) as USRCREATED_PROFILE_IMG,mm.DTCREATED
                              FROM kbedumoment mm
                              left join users md on mm.USRCREATED=md.USERKEY

where mm.id in
(
1264,253,238,1
)                              


order by mm.id desc
```

Duration: 0.016 sec 
EXPLAIN
[image]

Why is this happening ?

Comment: For something like this where obvious explanation fails, you should try running `EXPLAIN` on your query.  Perhaps MySQL has a step which could explain the behavior.

Comment: Post added with EXPLAIN.

Comment: Not an answer, but for some reason MySQL is using a range scan in your last query, but an index scan in the actual query of interest.  Range should outperform index, and this could explain the numbers.  But I don't know how to fix this.  You might want to worry about this when you have much larger tables.  Your expectations may play out with larger data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
SELECT PROJECTKEY,
    CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS USRCREATED,
    CONCAT('/userImages/', md.USERKEY, '/', md.IMAGE) AS USRCREATED_PROFILE_IMG,
    mm.DTCREATED
FROM kbedumoment mm
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT mm.id
        FROM kbedumoment mm
            LEFT JOIN kbedumomentpostto pt ON pt.MOMENT_ID = mm.id
        WHERE mm.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND pt.childkey = 1005 
        UNION 
        SELECT id
        FROM kbedumoment mm
        WHERE POST_TO = 'school'
            AND mm.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND mm.PROJECTKEY = 2
    ) temp ON temp.id = mm.id
    LEFT JOIN users md ON mm.USRCREATED = md.USERKEY
ORDER BY mm.id DESC;
```

What I used here is to use you pre existing subquery that has `&&` and replaced it with `AND` then use it as a generated table for `INNER JOIN` because both records must exists between `mm` and `temp`.

I also enhanced the format, so that you can read the query in a better perspective. Cheers

Comment: additional, you can add `SET SESSION tx_isolation = 'READ-COMMITTED';` before your query, so that your session can only read `committed` data